# Overridden virtual method in C#

Tags: c#

In "The C# Programming Language" book Eric Lippert mentioned this:

*A subtle point here is that an overridden virtual method is still considered to be a method of the class that introduced it, and not a method of the class that overrides it.*

What is the significance of this statement? Why does it matter if the overridden virtual method is considered to be a method of the class that introduced it (or otherwise) since the overridden method will never be called unless you are dealing with the derived class?

Comment: Probably matters if you are using reflection.

Comment: @TonyBasile it has to do with overload resolution, not reflection.

Comment: I think @PeterRitchie is right about this being unrelated to reflection. When overriding a virtual method in a class and reflecting on that class with `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, that overridden method is returned nonetheless.

Comment: The complete statement has this following what boon quoted: "The overload resolution rules in some cases prefer members of more derived types to those in base types; overirding a method does not "move" where that method belongs in this hierarchy."

Answer (score 6):

It matters when you have a reference of one type pointing to an object of a different type.

Example:

```
public class BaseClass {
  public virtual int SomeVirtualMethod() { return 1; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  public override int SomeVirtualMethod() { return 2; }
}

BaseClass ref = new DerivedClass();
int test = ref.SomeVirtualMethod(); // will be 2
```

Because the virtual method is a member of the base class, you can call the overriding method with a reference of the base class type. If it wasn't, you would need a reference of the derived type to call the overriding method.

When you are shadowing a method instead of overriding it, the shadowing method is a member of the derived class. Depending on the type of the reference you will be calling the original method or the shadowing method:

```
public class BaseClass {
  public int SomeMethod() { return 1; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  public new int SomeMethod() { return 2; }
}

BaseClass ref = new DerivedClass();
int test = ref.SomeMethod(); // will be 1

DerivedClass ref2 = ref;
int test2 = ref2.SomeMethod(); // will be 2
```

Comment: So his point applies to all modern languages that uses polymorphism, correct?

Comment: @Boon: Yes, that's simply how virtual methods work, so it applies to any object oriented language.

Comment: His point still doesn't make sense.  If BaseClass reference is holding onto a DerivedClass instance, you are technically still holding onto DerivedClass, so the method still belongs to the DerivedClass instance.  He can say the BaseClass introduces the original definition or implementation, but it doesn't make sense to say that "overridden virtual method is still considered to be a method of the class that introduced it", that made it sound like the BaseClass owns it, or that the implementation lives in the BaseClass.

Comment: @Boon: Compare it to a shadowed method, where the methods belong to the class that implements them. The method to call is determined at compile time based on the reference type. For a virtual method the overriding methods are essentially hidden from everything but the internal mechanism handling virtual calls. The virtual method defined in the base class is the only one that you can call, and then it's determined at runtime which method will handle the call based on the actual type of the object.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the full quote from the book:

> A subtle point here is that an overridden virtual method is still considered to be a method of the class that introduced it, and not a method of the class that overrides it. The overload resolution rules in some cases prefer members of more derived types to those in base types; overriding a method does not "move" where that method belongs in this hierarchy.
>
> At the very beginning of this section, we noted that C# was designed with versioning in mind. This is one of those features that helps prevent "brittle base-class syndrome" from causing versioning problems.

The full quote makes it clear that Eric Lippert is talking specifically about *method overloading*, not just about how virtual methods work.

As an example, consider the following program:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void M2(int i) { }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public void M1(int i) { Console.WriteLine("Derived.M1(int)"); }
    public void M1(float f) { Console.WriteLine("Derived.M1(float)"); }

    public override void M2(int i) { Console.WriteLine("Derived.M2(int)"); }
    public void M2(float f) { Console.WriteLine("Derived.M2(float)"); }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.M1(1);
        d.M2(1);
    }
}
```

I think many developers would be surprised that the output is

```
Derived.M1(int)
Derived.M2(float)
```

Why would `d.M2(1)` invoke `Derived.M2(float)` even though `Derived.M2(int)` is a better match?

When the compiler is determining what the `M1` in `d.M1(1)` refers to, the compiler sees that both `M1(int)` and `M1(float)` are introduced in `Derived`, so both overloads are applicable candidates. The compiler selects `M1(int)` over `M1(float)` as the best match for the integer argument `1`.

When the compiler is determining what the `M2` in `d.M2(1)` refers to, the compiler sees that `M2(float)` is introduced in `Derived` and is an applicable candidate. According to the overload resolution rules, "methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable". Because `M2(float)` is applicable, this rule prevents `M2(int)` from being a candidate. Even though `M2(int)` is a better match for the integer argument and even though it's overridden in `Derived`, it's still considered to be a method of `Base`.

Comment: +1 Wow. Great answer, I surely was surprised! What's with the downvotes?

Comment: @Cristi: In an earlier revision, I accidentally wrote "The full quote makes it clear that Eric Lippert is talking specifically about method overloading, not overriding" instead of "... not **just** overriding." I edited my answer after the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that an overridden virtual method belongs to the class which introduces it, rather than the class that overrides it, makes it easier to understand the way class members are bound.  Except when using `dynamic` objects, all bindings in C# are resolved at compile time.  If a `BaseClass` declares a virtual method `foo`, and `DerivedClass:BaseClass` overrides `foo`, code which attempts to call `foo` on a variable of type `BaseClass` will always be bound to virtual method "slot" `BaseClass.foo`, which will in turn point to the actual `DerivedClass.foo` method.

This understanding can be especially important when dealing with generics, since in C#, unlike C++, members of generic types are bound according to the generics' constraints, rather than according to the concrete generic types.  For example, suppose there were a `SubDerivedClass:DerivedClass` which created a `new virtual` method `foo()`, and one defined a method `DoFoo<T>(T param) where T:BaseClass {param.foo();}`.  The `param.foo()` call would be bound to `BaseClass.foo` even if the method were invoked as `DoFoo<SubDrivedClass>(subDerivedInstance)`.  If the parameter were cast to `SubDerivedClass` before invoking `foo`, the call would be bound to `SubDrivedClass.foo()`, but the compiler can't tell when producing `DoFoo<T>` that `T` will be anything more specific than `BaseClass`, it can't bind to anything that doesn't exist in `BaseClass`.

Incidentally, there are times it would be useful if a class could simultaneously override a base-class member and create a new one; for example, given an abstract base class `ReadableFoo` with some abstract read-only property, it would be helpful if a class `MutableFoo` could both provide an override for that property and define a read-write property with the same name.  Unfortunately, .net does not allow that.  Given such a restriction, the best approach may be for `ReadableFoo` to provide a concrete non-virtual read-only property which calls an `protected abstract` method with a different name to get the value.  That way, a derived class could shadow the read-only property with a read-write one (that would call the same virtual method for reading, or a new (possibly virtual) method for writing.

(following is untested)

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void foo() {Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.Foo");
}
class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override void foo() {Console.WriteLine("Derived.Foo");
}
class SubDerivedClass:DerivedClass
{
    public new virtual void foo() {Console.WriteLine("SubDerived.Foo");
}
class MegaDerivedClass:SubDerivedClass
{
    public override void foo() {Console.WriteLine("MegaDerived.Foo");
}
void DoFoo1<T>(T param) where T:BaseClass 
    {
        param.foo();
}
void DoFoo1<T>(T param) where T:SubDerivedClass 
    {
        param.foo();
}
void test(void)
{
    var megaDerivedInstance = new MegaDerivedClass();
    DoFoo1<MegaDerivedClass>(megaDerivedInstance);
    DoFoo2<MegaDerivedClass>(megaDerivedInstance);
}
```

A SubDerivedClass has two virtual `foo()` methods: `BaseClass.foo()` and `SubDerivedClass.foo()`.  A `MegaDerivedClass` has those same two methods.  Note that classes derived from `SubDerivedClass()` which attempt to override `foo` will override `SubDerivedClass.foo()` and will not affect `BaseClass.foo()`; with the declarations as above, no derivative of `SubDerivedClass` can override `BaseClass.Foo`.  Note also that casting an instance of `SubDerivedClass` or a subclass thereof to `DerivedClass` or `BaseClass` will expose the `BaseClass.foo` virtual method for calling.

Incidentally, if the method declaration in `SubDerivedClass` had been `friend new virtual void foo() {Console.WriteLine("SubDerived.Foo");`, it would be impossible for other classes within the same assembly to override `BaseClass.foo()` (since any attempt to override `foo()` would override `SubDerivedClass.foo()`), but classes outside the assembly which derive from `SubDerivedClass` wouldn't see `SubDerivedClass.foo()` and could thus override `BaseClass.foo()`.